# Problems with floating two divs side by side (both not following wrapper width)

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

First off, excuse my lack of knowledge regarding CSS and HTML. I'm quite new to this.

I've read most of the questions here regarding aligning two divs side by side here, I've also read some tutorials. But for some reason, I'm having trouble with the divs length in my code.

[This is the test site's URL, to give you guys an idea of how it looks.](http://abyssalchronicles.com/3revtest/acver3_base.html)

And here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
    <title>Okamainakute ne~</title>  
    <link href="acver3style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>  

<body>  

    <div id="main_wrapper">  

        <div id="banner_area">

                    <div id="logo">
                        <a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com"><img src="images/acver3_sitelogo.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="xillia">
                        <img src="images/acver3_toxlogo.png" /><br />
                            <div class="xilliacountry"><img src="images/acver3_toxus.png" /><br /></div>
                                <div class="xilliashops"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/gamestop.png" alt="" /></a> <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/playasia.png" alt="" /></a>  <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/amazon.png" alt="" /></a><br /></div>
                            <div class="xilliacountry"><img src="images/acver3_toxeu.png" /><br /></div>
                                <div class="xilliashops"><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/zavvi.png" alt="" /></a> <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/shopto.png" alt="" /></a>  <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/playasia.png" alt="" /></a><br /></div>
                    </div>

        </div>

        <div id="maincontent">

            <div class="menu_area">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com">HOME/NEWS</a></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/tales-of">TALES OF... »</a>
                            <ul>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/tales-of/type">By Type</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/tales-of/platform">By Platform</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/features">FEATURES »</a>
                            <ul>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/features/media">Media</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/features/columns">Columns</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/features/reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/features/fanworks">Fan Works</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://gallery.abyssalchronicles.com" target="_blank">GALLERY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://forums.abyssalchronicles.com" target="_blank">FORUMS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/the-site">THE SITE »</a>
                            <ul>
                                    <li><a href="http://wwww.abyssalchronicles.com/the-site/ACs-history">AC's History</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/the-site/staff">Site Staff</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/the-site/affiliates">Affiliation</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.abyssalchronicles.com/the-site/contact-form">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>


                <div id="socialgels">
                    &nbsp<a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/fbgel.png" alt="" /></a> <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/twgel.png" alt="" /></a> <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/tmgel.png" /></a> <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/ytgel.png" alt="" /></a> <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/rsgel.png" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div id="highlights">
                    <img src="images/sample_highlightsfader.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>

                <div id="ads">
                    <img src="images/sample_ad.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>





        </div>  

    </div>  


</body>  
</html>
```

And the CSS for that:

```
body {
    margin:0; padding:0;
    background:#0e564b url('images/ver3_banner.jpg') no-repeat center top;
}

a img {
    border:0;
}

img {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
}

#main_wrapper {
    width:983px;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:0;
}

#logo {
    width:750px;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}

#xillia {
    width:222px;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}

#socialgels {
    width:255px;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 2px;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align: right;
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}

#maincontent {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 3px #062521;
    width:983px;
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
    float:left;
}

#highlights{
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 17px;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    background: url('images/highlights_bg.gif') #f0f8ff no-repeat top left;
    vertical-align:top;
    float:left;
}

#ads {
    padding:10px 17px 10px 0px;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    background: url('images/ads_bg.gif') #f0f8ff no-repeat top right;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.xilliacountry {
    text-indent:40px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.xilliashops {
    text-indent:75px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.menu_area {
    background: url('images/ver3_menubg.jpg') #ab528c no-repeat;
    height:42px;
    border-top:#6a6a6b solid 1px;
    border-bottom:6a6a6b solid 1px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #660643;
    z-index:2;
    positon: absolute;
}

.menu_area ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

.menu_area ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

.menu_area li {
    float: left;
}

.menu_area ul a {
    background-image: url('images/menu_bg_divider.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding: 11px 16px 11px 16px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu_area ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b95a94;
}

.menu_area ul ul {
    display: none;
    background: #bb5c96;
    background-image: none;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 152px;
    z-index:2;
}

.menu_area ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #e6b5d5;
        position: relative;
}

.menu_area ul ul li a {
            padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
            color: #fff;
            background: none;
}   

.menu_area ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #e385c1;
}
```

The two divs I'm trying to align together are the **highlights** and **ads** divs. They're contained within a wrapper div named **maincontent**, and the said two divs are located below another div named **menu_area**. I think I should also note that within the main_area div, there's also a div for the social buttons you see at the right, named **socialgels**.

Anyway, as you can see in the demo page, the divs highlights and ads are aligned no problem, but that's because I had to decrease the width given to those divs. I want the site to strictly be 983px wide only, hence why the other parent divs you see in the code (the **main_wrapper** and **banner_area** divs) are set at 983px. The maincontent div is also set at that. As such, the *highlights* div was supposed to be set at 662px and the ads div at 321 px, with highlights floating left and ads floating right. That way, they equal 983px. However, when I do set it like that, for some reason they just won't place side by side: the ads div would always position itself below the highlights div. OR at times (I seriously have no idea what happened), the ads div would position itself to the very far right, as if there's this invisible space between the highlights and ads div that I just don't know where it comes from. They align properly when there are no widths indicated for both divs (that's how the demo page is, currently), but I can't have it like that.

[Here's a look of the page when there're indicated widths for both divs.](http://abyssalchronicles.com/3revtest/acver3_base_2.html)

Apologies if it was long. Basically, I really need to set those specific widths to the highlights and ads div because I don't want the upcoming content I'll be adding below them (the actual posts, and the rest of the navigation at the right, and such), to ruin the layout. I really need it at that specific 983px width.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forget the padding. If you set the width of the highlight div to 662px you must add the 17px padding and end up with 679px.

So to solve your problem there are two solutions:

Just subtract the padding and/or margin from your desired width.

662px - 17px = 645px

321px - 17px = 304px

Or you use `box-sizing: border-box` on the highlight and the ads div. If you now set the width to 662px, the padding is inside of the width.

Comment: Hi. I've tried as you said and changed the width of the highlights div to 645 and the ads div to 304. I've also added the box-sizing: border-box to both of them, but the results are still the same. It still shows up [like this](http://abyssalchronicles.com/3revtest/acver3_base_2.html)

Comment: Wait, actually it DID work a bit, I think, but for some reason, the ad image won't move to the left properly, even with a padding of 17px at the right. I tried increasing that value but it won't move. There's still this big space between the two divs :(.

Comment: You just have to do one thing. Resize the divs OR set box-sizing: border-box. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Ah, I got it! Either of them alone worked! Thank you very much! I'll just go with subtracting the padding. Thanks again!